# Start Symfony project

Tags: symfony, symfony3.x

I wanted to try to refresh my Symfony skills, because I stopped in Symfony v2. And I know the v4 just came out.

I created my project like that:

```
Latitude-5580:/var/www$ php symfony.phar new Symfony 3.4.16
```

This had the effect to create the Symfony folder inside www/

From this point I thought I would have access to the default bundle from Symfony, so I tried

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php
```

But I have an error 404. (Localhost is working).

The first thing who came to my mind was this might be related to the update from v2 to v3; and I saw v3 had some kind of light intern server.

So I did:

```
Latitude-5580:/var/www/Symfony$ php bin/console server:start

                                                                            
 [OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

From this point I tried:

```
http://localhost:8000/Symfony/web/app_dev.php
```

And this time I have a Symfony error (which is kind of the same but directly from Symfony instead of apache).

> Uncaught PHP Exception
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
> route found for "GET /Symfony/web/app_dev.php"" at
> /var/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php
> line 139

I don't understand why I do not have access to the first page with the default downloaded Symfony (the one who said I think 'Welcome to Symfony 3.4.16'.

Comment: Your route to default controller is http://localhost:8000. Routing != path/to/file. [Routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html)

Comment: Oh I see, that means http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php from V2 has been replaced by localhost:8000 in the V3 ? Indeed this localhost is working now.

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick So when I use localhost:8000 how do I know if the page is generated by the app.php or the app_dev.php ?

Comment: 4.x has been out for over a year.  No point in learning 3.4 unless you need to support legacy apps.  The symfony installer is no more.  The directory structure has changed significantly.  No more AppBuundle.  Use the composer create-project capability and just follow the docs.

Comment: @Minirock When using the built in server from the command line, it will always use dev environment.

Comment: @Minirock localhost:8000/app_dev.php call dev environment

Comment: @Cerad that's exactly what I will have to do in a week, otherwise I will be looking at the v4 obviously^^